# Excel: Add the date of the last modification on a row

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, runtime-error

I'm trying to add the date and time of the last time a row was modified to a specific column of that row with the following VBA Script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    ThisRow = Target.Row
    If Target.Row > 1 Then Range("K" & ThisRow).Value = Now()
End Sub
```

But it keeps throwing the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
>
> Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Why do you have `Target As Excel.Range` instead of `Target As Range`?

Comment: I tried it out but none of both where working.

Comment: Strange, I just tried both and they both work for me. Googling the error message doesn't help much either. Try something as simple as `Range("A1").Value = 5` and see if that gives you errors.

Comment: Don't consider it duplicate because after searching a lot I didn't come across that question. It is though related. Thank you a lot! ;-)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate.  It's identical in cause, effect, and solution.  It is the 3rd result in votes when [searching for](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bexcel%5d%20worksheet_change) `[excel] worksheet_change` on SO.  Of course I link to that answer several times a week so I know how to find it. :)

Comment: That explains a lot! :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an infinite loop by changing a value inside a `Worksheet_Change` event without disabling events first.  When I do something similar, I get a range of errors from `Out of stack space` first to `Method Range failed...`.

Do this instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ThisRow = Target.Row
    If Target.Row > 1 Then Range("K" & ThisRow).Value = Now()

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Related post: [MS Excel crashes when vba code runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)